# Is sizeof(bool) defined in the C++ language standard?

Tags: c++, boolean, sizeof, implementation-defined-behavior

I can't find an answer in the standard documentation. Does the C++ language standard require `sizeof(bool)` to always be 1 (for 1 byte), or is this size implementation-defined?

Comment: If your code depends on `bool` to be 1 byte, you can check it at compile-time: `static_assert(sizeof(bool) == 1, "OMG bool is big here");`.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

`sizeof(bool)` is implementation defined, and the standard puts notable emphasis on this fact.

§5.3.3/1, abridged:

> `sizeof(char)`, `sizeof(signed char)` and `sizeof(unsigned char)` are 1; the result of `sizeof` applied to any other fundamental type is implementation-defined. [Note: in particular, `sizeof(bool)` and `sizeof(wchar_t)` are implementation-defined.<sup>69)</sup>]

Footnote 69):

> `sizeof(bool)` is not required to be 1.

Comment: is there a flag that i need to compile my program with, that my compiler will use only 1 byte for `bool`?

Comment: @Eagle: That's up to your compiler, I'm not sure. It's probably best you left it up to your compiler.

Comment: note that std::vector<bool> is optimized to a vector containing  1bit bools by the standard.

Comment: @user3063349 Any reference?

Comment: @user3063349 is it standard really? [This](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) mentions implementation-dependence

Answer (score 21):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf4dy80a.aspx

"In Visual C++4.2, the Standard C++ header files contained a typedef that equated bool with int. In Visual C++ 5.0 and later, bool is implemented as a built-in type with a size of 1 byte. That means that for Visual C++ 4.2, a call of sizeof(bool) yields 4, while in Visual C++ 5.0 and later, the same call yields 1. This can cause memory corruption problems if you have defined structure members of type bool in Visual C++ 4.2 and are mixing object files (OBJ) and/or DLLs built with the 4.2 and 5.0 or later compilers."

Comment: You do realize that this is somewhat related to the question, but clearly not an answer, since 0xbadf00d asked about the standard, not some specific/arbitrarily selected compiler implementation, right?

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig It is a proof by counterexample.

Comment: @kinokijuf It's not a counterexample. There are many things in Visual C++ that are not standard-compliant.

Answer (score 12):

It's implementation defined. Only `sizeof(char)` is `1` by the standard.

Comment: pls note that the 1 in the standard can mean 4 byte. Than every type is a product of 4. So care that the standard ONLY defines char is the 1, but not defines the measurment.

Comment: 1 means 8 bits or 1 byte in the standard

Comment: 1 byte. The number of bits per byte is not defined by the standard (it needs to be at least 8 IIRC), but can be found in `CHAR_BIT`, defined in `climits`.

Comment: `sizeof(unsigned char)` and `sizeof(signed char)` also have to be `1` by the standard

Answer (score 3):

See 5.3.3 paragraph 1 :

> [Note: in particular, sizeof(bool) and
>   sizeof(wchar_t) are
>   implementation-defined.69) ]