# adding two bool values in c/c++

Tags: c++

I tried to add bool value together, say:

`bool i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;`
`cout << sizeof(i + j + k) << endl;`

The result is 4, which means, the result is converted to a 'int' value.

I want to ask: Is this a C/C++ standard operation? does the compiler always guarantee that the temporary value to be converted to a larger type if it overflows? Thanks!

Thanks for the answers, one follow up question:
say, if I do:
`unsigned short i = 65535, j = 65535;`
`cout << sizeof(i + j) << endl;`
The result is 4. Why it's been promoted to 'int'?

Comment: an int is not a larger type than a bool

Comment: Does the compiler always guarantee that the temporary value to be converted to a larger type if it overflows? No, it never converts a value to larger type until a cast is requested.

Comment: @aaronman: In most implementations `sizeof(bool) < sizeof(int)` which many people will refer to as *`int` is a larger type [more bits] than `bool`*.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, I think you mean `<`.

Comment: @CarlNorum: lol... yes, I meant `<` (and I have corrected the original `>` in the comment)

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages, and they define `bool` differently. (Prior to the 1999 ISO standard, C didn't define `bool` at all.)

Comment: I use `AND` in `QBASIC` not `PLUS`, there is a catch about `AND` or `PLUS` in `BOOL talk`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's not the overflow that causes the conversion, it's the very fact you did arithmetic at all.  In C++ (and C where the behaviour originated), the operands of basic arithmetic operators on built-in types go through a set of well-defined promotions before the calculation is made.  The most of basic of these rules (somewhat simplified) is that any type smaller than an `int` gets promoted to `int`.

Your followup question has the same answer - your `short` is smaller than an `int`, so it gets promoted to an `int` before the addition takes place.

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563000/implicit-type-conversion-rules-in-c-operators) has several answers that describe the promotions in more detail.

Comment: I didn't say it was, did I?  I guess I could prefix my answer with "if there is a conversion".

Comment: STL has a nice video on the subject as well. Core C++ 7.

Answer (score 2):

First, `sizeof` doesn't tell you that the result is converted to an `int` value. It is allowed, and indeed not uncommon, that `bool` has the same size as `int`.

However you will indeed get an `int` here, but that's unrelated to the values (indeed, the type cannot depend on the values because in general the values will not be known until runtime, while the type must be determined at compile time).

What happens is that before adding, the `bool` values get promoted to `int` because `bool` is defined as an integer type, and integer types smaller than `int` *all* get promoted to `int`. You then add three `int` values (an operation which doesn't overflow no matter what `bool` values you use, because `INT_MAX` is guaranteed to be larger than 3).

Comment: Yeah, if you count wrist watches and the gazillion other embedded 8bit micro-controllers. I reckon on all modern compilers and platforms I've seen it is a single byte. So a bool can be the size of an int only on 8 bit platforms.

Comment: Even on an 8-bit micro, `int` has to be at least 16 bits.  I'd guess even there they're not the same size.

Comment: @ddriver: The point is not that `int` might be 8 bit (it can't), but that `bool` may be larger than one byte. And that's not only a theoretical issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6935286/1032073