# the built-in type bool in C++ or the stdbool.h type in C defines TRUE and FALSE as not the size of the machine word?

Tags: c++, c

I was under the impression that `bool` types either in C or C++ were typdef'ed integers because it was "easier" to handle at the machine level (size of word and what not). But I just did a `sizeof` and, to my surprise, they return 1 (byte). Is this right? Well, it is, as per my own short experiment, by why does everything tell me I should be using integers?

Just for the sake of interest, see the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type#C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_Objective-C.2C_Awk.2C_Perl) on boolean data types for C.

Comment: In C++, `bool` is a built in type that is one byte and we don't have `<stdbool.h>`. So I think this question is improperly tagged.

Comment: `bool` is a native type in C++, and a typedef for the native `_Bool` in C99 and C11.

Comment: @Rapptz: `bool` is not necessarily 1 byte

Comment: I know. I'm more interested in the rationale than the datatype. My question is: why a char? is that defined in the c++ standard?

Comment: May be I am correct: because bool are nor originally in C, we generally defined it as `typedef enum{FALSE, TRUE} bool` and enums are int

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Yes, if we want to be pedantic then we can say it doesn't have to be 1 byte. Similar to the equivalent of having the possibility of a 64-bit `char`.

Comment: I made a mistake in my exp, in fact, `sizeof(true)` is indeed an `int`. Phew. Still interested in the C++ case.

Comment: @Rapptz: A `char` is *always* one byte. That's the very definition of "byte".

Comment: @DervinThunk: `sizeof(true)` is a `size_t`, not an `int`.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Maybe you do generally define it that way, but that really not relevant to either c++ or `<stdbool.h>`

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes, fine. Just not one byte. In any case, the opengroup says it expands to an integer...

Comment: @KerrekSB I did not say otherwise. However `CHAR_BIT` is required to be >= 8 and `sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)` is entirely a possibility according to the standard. Which is what I meant with my pedantry comment there.

Comment: @Rapptz On the system I work on sizeof(bool) == 4.

Comment: @BrianNeal: Cool. what system is that?

Comment: A PowerPC based embedded system. See Mats Petersson's answer for the reasoning.

Comment: @KerrekSB: That is not true. `sizeof(char)==1` (byte), but that does not mean that it is 8 bits. The term `byte` in the standard does not have a fixed size. A `byte` in C++ could be 10bits. Now, while it might not seem practical, in some target architectures (some DSPs, for example), a `char` is actually 32bits.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: That would mean that on those systems a byte is 32 bit wide, non?

Comment: @sehe yes, I just read C++ 10 years back in my school, I didn't revised.

Comment: @KerrekSB: yes, but if you ask anyone other than a pedantic C++ standard student, *byte* means 8bits.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: No, if I ask one of those, they'll say, "how do I marshal that into an `ArrayList<Byte>` so it can be garbage collected"...

Comment: Whoever is still giving upvotes to Rapptz's first comment, please stop. I did change the title to better reflect my interest in both languages. It's getting confusing.

Comment: @KerrekSB: In C99 and C11, `bool` is actually a macro, not a typedef, for `_Bool`. (A typedef would IMHO have been cleaner, but it might be handy to `#undef bool` in some cases.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yes, sorry, I meant that... thanks for the correction. All the "correct-looking" additions to C are macros for underscore-capital kewords (e.g. `_Thread_local` and `_Atomic`...)

Comment: @DervinThunk: Your question title assumes that anything with a size of 1 byte is a `char`. That's a bad assumption. Even if `bool` and `char` (or `_Bool` and `char`) happen to be the same size, they're distinct types.

Comment: @KeithThompson: somewhat fixed. now it's clunkier, but more correct, I suppose.

Comment: @DervinThunk: Changing "as a char" to "as a byte" would probably be clearer (since "byte" isn't a type).

Comment: @KeithThompson: I thought so too for a minute, but I wanted to convey that idea of "something different than the size of the word". I've changed my preconceptions of the whole thing now, but that was the original spirit of the question. In any case, that's good, that's what discussions are good for :)

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897844/is-sizeofbool-defined

Answer (score 9):

C++11 spec, section 3.9.1 [basic.fundamental], paragraph 6:

> Values of type `bool` are either `true` or `false`. [Note: There are no
>   signed, unsigned, short, or long bool types or values. — end note ]
>   Values of type bool participate in integral promotions (4.5).

Section 5.3.3 [expr.sizeof], paragraph 1:

> The `sizeof` operator yields the number of bytes in the object
>   representation of its operand. The operand is either an expression,
>   which is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5), or a parenthesized
>   type-id. The `sizeof` operator shall not be applied to an expression
>   that has function or incomplete type, to an enumeration type whose
>   underlying type is not ﬁxed before all its enumerators have been
>   declared, to the parenthesized name of such types, or to an lvalue
>   that designates a bit-ﬁeld. `sizeof(char)`, `sizeof(signed char)` and `sizeof(unsigned char)` are 1. The result of `sizeof` applied to any other fundamental type (3.9.1) is
>   implementation-deﬁned. [**Note: in particular, `sizeof(bool)`,
>   `sizeof(char16_t)`, `sizeof(char32_t)`, and `sizeof(wchar_t)` are
>   implementation-deﬁned.** (75) — end note ]

Footnote (75) says:

> 75) `sizeof(bool)` is not required to be 1

The presence of the footnote suggests that `sizeof(bool)` equals 1 on enough implementations that they need to remind people it is not necessarily so.

Answer (score 7):

On SOME machines, `int` may be easier to handle than a byte-sized object. But for many processors, an `int` is no easier to deal with than a byte-sized integer. Since a byte takes less space (at least if you don't stick it next to an `int` so that the compiler needs to pad it), then you benefit in doing so in some situations.

I don't think the standard says anything about what size it actually MUST be. Edit: As the comment says, the C++ standard specifically says that the size is implementation defined, and is not required to be 1 (but it also doesn't say it CAN'T be 1). The standard also says that the value of a `bool` is `true` or `false`, but that if you "use" an uninitialized variable of type `bool`, it is undefined behaviour, and it can be something that is neither of those values.

There are a few processors (older Alpha, some variants of MIPS if my memory serves right) where bytes are "difficult" to handle (there are only instructions to read whole words, individual bytes has to be managed by masking, etc). On these processors, it would make sense to have a `int` sized type. And it wouldn't surprise me if that is the case on those machines. Remember, C and C++ are languages that allow types to vary in size depending on what is "good" on that particular architecture.

Comment: In my copy of the standard the result of `sizeof(bool)` is implementation-defined (5.3.3.1). There is even a footnote that specifically says "sizeof(bool) is not required to be 1".

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Thanks. I thought that was the case.

Answer (score 2):

In C:

`bool` is a macro that expands to `_Bool` and `_Bool` is a type that is neither `unsigned int`, `unsigned char` nor `int`.

For example, `_Bool` has this property:

```
(_Bool) 0.5  == 1
```

and none of the other standard integer types have this property.

C standard just says that `_Bool` is an unsigned integer type large enough to store values `0` and `1`. Also a `_Bool` object has at least `CHAR_BIT` as has any object of non-bit field type.

Regarding the size of `_Bool`, it is usually `1` (optimized for size) but on some systems it has the same size as the size of the word (for example `4` on some `32`-bit systems).

Comment: _Bool is indeed 1, but `true` is 4 on my 64-bit system.

Comment: @DervinThunk but `true` is not of type `_Bool` in C, but of type `int`

Comment: @Devin: In C, `true` is a macro that expands to `1`, which is a constant of type `int`. `sizeof true == sizeof (int)`, and it just happens to be 4 on your system. I think you'll also find that `sizeof '?' == sizeof (int)`, since character constants are of type `int`.

Comment: How do floating point values enter into it? Does the standard actually require rounding 0.5 to 1 and not 0? And different rounding requirements for `_Bool`? Your second assertion is baffling.

Comment: @Potatoswatter yes it does. See c99, 6.3.1.2p1

Comment: @ouah "When any scalar value is converted to `_Bool`, the result is 0 if the value compares equal to 0; otherwise, the result is 1." It might be more insightful to point out that `(_Bool) 0.1` or `(_Bool) nan()` are both `true`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the latest C standard, [C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), the `<stdbool.h>` header defines:

> **true**
>
> which expands to the integer constant 1,
>
> **false**
>
> which expands to the integer constant 0