# New with C, weird calloc() happenings

Tags: c

I allocate memory with calloc() but then it get's cleared when I call calloc to allocate more memory, later in the program.  I calloc num1bin inside of conv2bin and then it get's cleared back to all 0's when I calloc my luiArray.  Is this how it's supposed to work?  Am I missing something?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef int bool;

void printBinary(bool* bin, int size, FILE* outfile)
{
    for(int i=0; i<size; ++i)
    {
        fprintf(outfile, "%d", bin[i]);
    }
}

void printHex(char* hex, int size, FILE* outfile)
{
    for(int i=0; i<size; ++i)
    {
        fprintf(outfile, "%c", hex[i]);
    }
}

bool* conv2bin(int num)
{
    bool* bin = (bool*) calloc(1, 16);
    if(num > 65535 || num < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "NUMBER NOT AVAILABLE FOR 16BIT UNSIGNED BINARY\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int j = 0;
    for(int i=15; i>=0; --i, j++)
    {
        if(num >= (int) pow(2, i))
        {
            bin[j] = 1;
            num -= (int) pow(2,i);
        }
        else
        {
            bin[j] = 0;
        }
    }
    if(num != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "FUNCTION FAILED\n\n");
        printBinary(bin, 16, stderr);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return bin;
}

char* conv2hex(bool* bin)
{
    char* hex = (char*) calloc(1, 5);
    int j=0;
    for(int i=0; i<16; i+=4, ++j)
    {
        int hchar = 0;
        if(bin[i] == 1)
        {
            hchar += 8;
        }
        if(bin[i+1] == 1)
        {
            hchar += 4;
        }
        if(bin[i+2] == 1)
        {
            hchar += 2;
        }
        if(bin[i+3] == 1)
        {
            hchar += 1;
        }

        if(hchar < 10)
        {
            hex[j] = (char)(((int)'0')+hchar);
        }
        else if(hchar == 10)
        {
            hex[j] = 'A';
        }
        else if(hchar == 11)
        {
            hex[j] = 'B';
        }
        else if(hchar == 12)
        {
            hex[j] = 'C';
        }
        else if(hchar == 13)
        {
            hex[j] = 'D';
        }
        else if(hchar == 14)
        {
            hex[j] = 'E';
        }
        else if(hchar == 15)
        {
            hex[j] = 'F';
        }
    }
    return hex;
}

int multiply(int num1, int num2)
{
    for(int i=0; i<num2; ++i)
    {
        int carry;
        while(num2 != 0)
        {
            carry = (num1 & num2) << 1;
            num1 ^= num2;
            num2 = carry;
        }
    }
    return num1;
}

int divide(int num1, int num2, int* remain)
{
    int quotient = 0;
    if(num1 == num2)
    {
        (*remain) = 0;
        return 1;
    }
    else if(num1 < num2)
    {
        (*remain) = num1;
        return 0;
    }
    do
    {
        num2 <<= 1;
        quotient <<= 1;
    } while(num2 <= num1);

    return quotient = quotient + divide((num1 - num2), num2, remain);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE* infile;
    FILE* outfile;
    infile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    outfile = fopen(argv[2], "w");

    //check file integrity
    if(infile == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "CANNOT OPEN INPUT FILE!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(outfile == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "CANNOT OPEN OUTPUT FILE!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int num1, num2;
    fscanf(infile, "%d\n%d", &num1, &num2);

    fprintf(outfile, "%d\t%d\n", num1, num2);

    /*SIMULATING LUI AND ORI*/
    bool* num1bin = conv2bin(num1);
    bool* num2bin = conv2bin(num2);

    //print binary numbers
    printBinary(num1bin, 16, outfile);
    fprintf(outfile, "\t");
    printBinary(num2bin, 16, outfile);
    fprintf(outfile, "\n");
    printBinary(num1bin, 16, stderr);

    //allocate memory and write binary numbers into it
    bool* luiArray = (bool*) calloc(1, 32);
printBinary(num1bin, 16, stderr);
    int j=0;
    for(int i=15; i>=0; --i, ++j)
    {
        luiArray[i] = num1bin[j];
    }
    //print out array after first 16 loaded into it
    printBinary(luiArray, 32, outfile);
    fprintf(outfile, "\n");
    j=16;
    for(int i=31; i>=16; --i, ++j)
    {
        luiArray[i] = num1bin[j];
    }

    printBinary(luiArray, 32, outfile);
    fprintf(outfile, "\n");
    free(luiArray);

    /*BITWISE MULTIPLY AND DIVIDE*/
    int product = multiply(num1, num2);
    fprintf(outfile, "%d * %d = %d\n", num1, num2, product);
    int quotient, remain;
    divide(num1, num2, &remain);
    fprintf(outfile, "%d / %d = %d (%d)\n", num1, num2, quotient, remain);

    /*LOGICAL OPERATORS*/
    int andresult = num1 & num2;
    bool* ares = conv2bin(andresult);
    char* hexand = conv2hex(ares);
    printBinary(ares, 16, outfile);
    fprintf(outfile, "\t");
    printHex(hexand, 4, outfile);
    fprintf(outfile, "\n");
    free(ares);

    int orresult = num1 | num2;
    bool* ores = conv2bin(orresult);
    char* hexor = conv2hex(ores);
    printBinary(ores, 16, outfile);
    fprintf(outfile, "\t");
    printHex(hexor, 4, outfile);
    fprintf(outfile, "\n");
    free(ores);

    int xorresult = num1 ^ num2;
    bool* xres = conv2bin(xorresult);
    char* hexxor = conv2hex(xres);
    printBinary(xres, 16, outfile);
    fprintf(outfile, "\t");
    printHex(hexxor, 4, outfile);
    fprintf(outfile, "\n");
    free(xres);

    int notresult = ~num2;
    bool* nres = conv2bin(notresult);
    char* hexnot = conv2hex(nres);
    printBinary(nres, 16, outfile);
    fprintf(outfile, "\t");
    printHex(hexnot, 4, outfile);
    fprintf(outfile, "\n");
    free(nres);

    free(num1bin);
    free(num2bin);

    fclose(infile);
    fclose(outfile);
    free(hexand);
    free(hexor);
    free(hexxor);
    free(hexnot);
    return 0;
}
```

Use a text file with just two positive numbers (78 and 123 are what I'm using) separated by a return for input.  Any text file for output.

Sorry for the confusion.  Thank you for the help.  And I'll update the pow() to bitshift at some point.

Comment: Show how you are printing.

Comment: Use bitwise shift rather than `pow`. No need for floating point arithmetic here. As for the question, stop describing what you do in comments, and put it in code. An SSCCE and it's easy to answer. As it stands it is hard to tell what surprises you.

Comment: A complete program that we can compile is what I ask for. You are nearly there. Please just make that final step. Then we can surely answer.

Comment: What is sizeof(bool) in ***C***?

Comment: [Is sizeof(bool) defined?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4897844)

Comment: `typedef int bool` is probably a bad idea.

Comment: @Grzegorz: Yes, apparently for MSVC: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf4dy80a.aspx. But maybe not for the OP's version of C?

Comment: Your edit to show `typedef int bool` somewhat changes the picture!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code:

```
typedef int bool;
```

means that `sizeof(bool) == sizeof(int)`. Your allocations assume that `sizeof(bool) == 1`. However, `sizeof(int) > 1`. Hence your program invokes undefined behaviour by writing off the end of an array.

Some other comments:

1. `pow()` performs floating point arithmetic. That's really not appropriate. You should use bitwise shifting.
2. Don't cast the return value of `malloc()`.
3. Are you quite sure that you want to typedef a type named `bool`? That seems a little imprudent to me. I would suggest that you include `stdbool.h` and use the standard C `bool`. Of course, you'll still want to use `sizeof()` rather than making any assumptions.

Comment: Thank you!  Also is there a better way to implement boolean representation in c that you know of?

Comment: Include `stdbool.h` and use `bool` as defined there

Answer (score 2):

After accept answer

Agree the size is wrong as @David Heffernan fine answer reports.

To avoid getting the size wrong in the *first* place, do not hard-code size.  Let the compiler derive it by using `sizeof *bin`.

```
 void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);

 // bool* bin = (bool*) calloc(1, 16);
 bool* bin = calloc(16, sizeof *bin);
```

---

Minor:
1) Subtle issues may occur in select compilers concerning the order of `calloc()` parameters.  Use `number_of_elements, size_of_one_element)`
2) No need to cast `calloc()` return value.