# Exporting Packed structures with bool

Tags: c++, c, c99

What is the best practice for exporting a packed structure containing booleans?

I ask this because I'm trying to find the best way to do that. Current I do:

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
#include <stdbool.h>    //size is 1.
#else
typedef enum {false, true} bool; //sizeof(int)
#endif
#endif
```

now in the above, the size of a boolean can be 1 or `sizeof(int)`..

So in a structure like:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct
{
    long unsigned int sock;
    const char* address;
    bool connected;
    bool blockmode;
} Sock;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

the alignment is different if using C compared to C99 & C++. If I export it as an integer then languages where boolean is size 1 have alignment problems and need to pad the structure.

I was wondering if it would be best to typedef a bool as a char in the case of pre-C99 but it just doesn't feel right.

Any better ideas?

Comment: What about using bit flags in an int field?

Comment: Wouldn't the size still be `sizeof(int)`? Can you elaborate?

Comment: The idea is to use 2 bit flags instead of 2 bools in whatever underlying integer field (int, short, char, whatever).

Comment: Suddenly we've got exactly this answer.

Comment: I would recommend using `stdint.h` (see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/)) to make the sizes of your datatypes explicit and reliable. That'll make it easier to handle alignment of packed structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you're looking for: preserve space but run a few extra instructions, or waste a few bytes but run faster.

If you're looking to be fast, but can "waste" a few bytes of space (i.e. a single value for each boolean flag, see [sizeof bool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897844/is-sizeofbool-defined) discussion), your current approach is the superior. That is because it can load and compare the boolean values directly without having to mask them out of a packed field (see next).

If you're looking to preserve space then you should look into [C bitfields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yszfawxh.aspx):

```
struct Sock {
    ...
    int connected:1; // For 2 flags, you could also use char here.
    int blockmode:1;
}
```

or roll your own "flags" and set bits in integer values:

```
#define SOCKFLAGS_NONE      0
#define SOCKFLAGS_CONNECTED (1<<0)
#define SOCKFLAGS_BLOCKMODE (1<<1)

struct Sock {
    ...
    int flags; // For 2 flags, you could also use char here.
}
```

Both examples lead to more or less the same code which masks bits and shifts values around (extra instructions) but is denser packed than simple `bool` values.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, using `#pragma pack` is more pain (in long term) than the gain (in short term).

- It is compiler specific; non-standard and non-portable
- I understand the embedded systems or protocols scenarios. With little extra effort, the code can be written pragma free.
- I too want to pack my structure as much as possible and lay out the members in wider-first way as you did. However, I do not mind losing 2 bytes, if that allows my code to be standard-compliant and portable.

I would do the following three things:

- Declare the flags as `bool` (you already did) and assign `true/false`
- Put them as last members of the `struct` (you already did)
- Use bitfield (as suggested by fellow stackers)

Combining these:

```
typedef struct Sock
{
    long unsigned int sock;
    const char* address;
    bool connected : 1;
    bool blockmode : 1;
} Sock;
```

Comment: The problem is that `bool connected: 1;` is a gcc-extension. It doesn't let you specify the `type` of a bitfield.

Comment: @Braondon: In my understanding and test, `bool connected : 1` is standard compliant. It compiles fine with `-std=XXX -pedantic` for `XXX = c99, c++98, c++0x`.

Answer (score 0):

In the pre-C99 case, it is risky to `typedef char bool;`. That will silently break code like:

```
bool x = (foo & 0x100);
```

which is supposed to set `x` to be true if that bit is set in `foo`. The enum has the same problem.

In my code I actually do `typedef unsigned char bool;` but then I am careful to write `!!` everywhere that an expression is converted to this `bool`. It's not ideal.

In my experience, using flags in an integral type leads to fewer issues than using `bool` in your structure, or bitfields, for C90.