# Return True or 1?

Tags: c, types, boolean

As I know, Boolean is basically a `char` datatype, one byte, `0x00` or `0x01`. Also, as I know, Integer is multiple bytes.

```
bool foo () {
    return true; // I guess is 0x01 one byte
    return 1; // I guess is 0x00000001 four bytes (depend on the platform)
}
```

Why do both returns work?

Comment: Since it is returning `bool`, use the corresponding values `true` and `false` for consistency.

Comment: Both work because C considers any number other than `0` to be true, and `0` of any type is considered false.

Comment: *As I know, Boolean is basically a char datatype* - this is not true. It is `_Bool`, whose underlying memory layout is only defined to be large enough to hold values `0` and `1`.

Comment: Ironically, for a language all about binary computing, "boolean" values were a serious afterthought in C. This is largely because a lot of things were already *logically* true or false and `1` and `0` already did the job. If your return type is `bool`, the proper thing to do is `return true`. Don't make it weird. There's an infinite number of things that also work, like `cos(0)` or `!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!0` but please don't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Casting int to bool in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31551888/casting-int-to-bool-in-c-c)

Comment: In general, C allows mixed-type expressions.  If you say `a = b`, but `a` and `b` do not have the same types, the compiler will attempt to automatically convert `b`'s value to the type of `a`.  Similarly, if you have a function `atype f() { btype b; b = ...; return b; }`, where the function is declared to return a value of one type ("`atype`") but you write a `return` statement involving an expression of another type (`"btype"`), the compiler will attempt to convert `b`'s value to type `atype`.

Comment: If such a conversion is possible, the compiler will perform it.  If the conversion is impossible, you'll get an error at compile time.  (Even if the conversion is possible, you may get a warning, if someone thinks that particular conversion might be a mistake, or a bad idea.  Conversions to type `bool` are almost always possible, however, with values that compare equal to `0` being considered "false", and all other values being considered "true".)

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments, I agree with you, I'm just wondering why `sizeof(bool)` in all platform 99% will give you 1, which mean 1 byte like a `char` datatype. Another thing is why a Microsoft Repo will use `return 1` in a bool function like here https://github.com/microsoft/jacdac-c/blob/65a3576993b466f462b20bfa6c74757259594fa5/services/hidmouse.c#L100

Answer (score 4):

Here is what the C 2017 standard says about `bool` (aka _Bool) so "basically a char" is not correct:

> An object declared as type _Bool is large enough to store the values 0 and 1. (6.2.5)

`return 1` works due to automatic type conversion:

> When any scalar value is converted to _Bool , the result is 0 if the value compares equal to 0; otherwise, the result is 1 (6.3.1.2)

There is no "best practice" as far as I know.  I did not see it covered in MISRA C for instance.  It may be covered in coding guidelines for your project(s) though.  I use 0 and 1 as I favor compact code.

Comment: Agreed: they are interchangeable as far as anyone familiar with C should read it. I personally prefer `true` and `false` when dealing with boolean values, as I think it better maps conceptually. But just so the OP is aware, there is a loud cohort of C people who have given me grief about that before. But +1 because using `0` and `1` is absolutely fine and idiomatic.

Answer (score 4):

As others have explained, the size of a `bool` is not specified by the standard, so a compiler implementation is free to use any size as long as it can hold the values 0 and 1.

My clear recommendation is to use a `bool` type if the information is true/false by nature. Using an integer as boolean can lead to subtle errors. Consider the following (inspired by a real-life bug):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

uint8_t isThisTrueInt(void)
{
    int x = 256;
    return x;
}

bool isThisTrueBool(void)
{
    int x = 256;
    return x;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", (isThisTrueInt())?"true":"false");
    printf("%s\n", (isThisTrueBool())?"true":"false");
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
false
true
```

The point being that converting 256 to an 8-bit integer truncates to 0, i.e. "false" while conversion to `bool` will give "true" for any non-zero integer.

Comment: I appreciate that real-life inspired bug.  Ouch.  I can't get gcc to emit  a warning (till you change the `int` to `uint8_t` or straight `return 256` for an overflow warning).  It would have taken me forever to find that bug as it offends my sensibilities :-)

Answer (score 2):

> *As I know, Boolean is basically a char datatype, one byte, 0x00 or 0x01*

That is not the case, the size of `bool` type is implementation-defined and is not specified in the C standard, it is usually defined in `stdbool.h` as of C99 and is normally something like:

```
#define bool  _Bool
#define false 0
#define true  1
```

Before that it wasn't even a mandated type. You can say that in some implementations it's equivalent to a single byte, but not always, the specification only requires that `bool` is large enough to hold the values 0 or 1 and this ranges from 1 bit to the largest type possible, natively `long long`.

---

> *What's the best practice to follow?*

This is an opinion based question, still, thinking about it, I would advise to use `true`/`false` because it's a pattern used in pretty much all the languages and it'll surely be easier to understand, I must admit I'm not the best follower of such practice as I often use 0/1.

This is all overrided by your project/company coding practices or guidelines, if that's the case.

---

> *Why do both returns work?*

In C, any non-zero value is considered to be `true` (this includes negative values) in a boolean context, whereas 0 is considered to be false as can be seen in **N1570 Committee Draft of April 12, 2011          ISO/IEC 9899:201x**:

##### §6.3.1.2 Boolean type

> *1 When any scalar value is converted to _Bool, the result is 0 if the value compares equal to 0; otherwise, the result is 1.<sup>59)</sup>*
>
> *Footnotes*
>
> *59) NaNs do not compare equal to 0 and thus convert to 1.*