# How do I break out of a while loop from within a switch in an if else statement in C?

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop, switch-statement

I was trying out simple activities about if statements, switches, and loops while studying programming and I ran into this problem.

```
while (1) {
    if (/*condition*/) {
           //error
    } else {
           switch (num) {
                 case 1:
                 break;
                 default:
                 //error
           }
    }
}
```

Apparently the `break;` statement only terminates the switch block, but not the loop.

I tried doing

```
int loop_break = 1;

while ( 1 && loop_break == 1) {
      if (/*condition*/) {
           //error
      } else {
           switch (num) {
                 case 1:
                 loop_break = 0;
                 break;
             }
      }
}
```

and it does work but is it really valid? i don't think this will be applicable for every problem. i'm thinking of just using goto but i want to try out other methods first

Comment: Yes, that works, yet the best solution depends of the larger _unposted_ code.

Comment: Can you put the code in a function?  It's then easy to return out of any degree of loop/switch nesting.

Comment: OT: Use a `bool` to represent true/false values instead of `int`. See e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75009552/11993121

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is the correct way. You do not need `1 &&`. I would also suggest to use variable names which show what they do. `loop_break` will rather indicate that you want to break the loop if it is `true`

```
while (stayInLoop) {
      if (/*condition*/) {
           //error
      } else {
           switch (num) {
                 case 1:
                 stayInLoop = 0;
                 break;
             }
      }
}
```

If you have a very complicated break loop logic you can also consider `goto`

```
while (1) {
      if (/*condition*/) {
           //error
      } else {
           switch (num) {
                 case 1:
                 goto outsideTheLoop;
             }
      }
}
outsideTheLoop:
```

Comment: +1, especially with errors that are triggered from multiple points,`goto` _may_ lead to more readable code, in the absence of an exception mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Or simply:

```c
    while (1) {
        if (/*condition*/) {
            //error
        } else {
            switch (num) {
            case 1:
                goto escape;
            default:
                //error
            }
        }
    }
  escape:
    ;
```

That is the simplest, most efficient, and most readable approach.

Answer (score 0):

Write it as simple and readable as possible:

```
bool loop = false;

while (loop && !error) 
{
  switch (num) 
  {
    case 1:
      loop = false;
      break;
    ...
  }
}

if(error)
{
  /* handle error */    
}
```

There's no need to keep the error handling inside the loop body. Or if the error wasn't really critical enough to stop the loop, well what does it do then, more specifically?

Nor is there a need to conjure all manner of spaghetti programming with goto/continue.

Answer (score -1):

"*but i want to try out other methods first*"

The following is an alternative. The scope of the *flag variable* `trouble` is limited to the loop itself. And, `continue` obviates the need for an additional level of indentation. It's another method that's quite readable.

```
for( int trouble = 0; !trouble; /* */ ) {
    if( /*condition*/ ) {
        /* error */
        continue;
    }

    switch( num ) {
        case 1: trouble++; break;
        /* and so on */
    }
}
```

If you're really clever, you might see how changing `!trouble` to `trouble < RETRIES` would allow `/*error*/` to perform some kind of *reset* for another attempt at satisfying `/*condition*/`... (Increment `trouble` before the `continue`, of course..)