# Setting SO_BROADCAST to a socket fails with "Invalid argument"

Tags: c++, xcode

My IDE: xCode, OS X 10.10.4

```
int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
bool bc = true;
int ret = setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (const void*)&bc, sizeof(bool));
if(ret < 0){
    perror("set opt err:");
}
sockaddr_in tarAddr;
memset(&tarAddr, 0, sizeof(sockaddr_in));
tarAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
tarAddr.sin_port = htons(5000);
tarAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_BROADCAST;

char szMsg[100] = {0};
strcpy(szMsg, "hello");

int len = sizeof(sockaddr);
ret = sendto(s, szMsg, strlen(szMsg), 0, (sockaddr*)&tarAddr, len);
if(ret < 0){
    perror("sendto err:");
}
close(s);
```

The above code is about send udp message to broadcast, but the result info is:

```
set opt err: Invalid argument
sendto err: Permission denied
```

and the same code go fine in vc++/windows.

Comment: Second error is a result of first one - man page describes this error as "An attempt was made to send to a network/broadcast address as though it was a unicast address."

Comment: `socket` function can fail and then it returns -1 instead of descriptor. You don't check for this. Try checking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the argument `sizeof(bool)` returns an invalid value. As you can see in the following link, it is not defined that `sizeof(bool)`should deliver 1.

[Is sizeof(bool) defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897844/is-sizeofbool-defined)

I also think that you don't have to cast the pointer in the function call. It would be enough only to have the `&`.

Can you provide some code of the `sendto()`function to determine the other error?

Comment: What's wrong is the bool. It _may_ work as expected on little endian computers, but it really should be an int.

Answer (score 1):

I changed bc to int and this solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

As has been insinuated, your *optval* is wrong.

From [the `socket` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html):

> The socket options listed below can be set by using setsockopt(2) and
>          read with getsockopt(2) with the socket level set to SOL_SOCKET for
>          all sockets.  Unless otherwise noted, **optval is a pointer to an int**.

You're giving it a pointer to a `bool` instead.

Fortunately, the function is able to detect this (possibly `sizeof(bool)` differs from `sizeof(int)` on your platform, or otherwise its reinterpreting a `bool` as an `int` simply results in a value it doesn't recognise; it's UB anyway), so you get a nice error telling you that your argument is wrong.

Remember, the function doesn't know the *type* of your data (as it gets a `void*`), so even if it *wanted* to be able to accept an `int` or a `bool` or `llama` it would have no way of doing so.