# Rotate a bool array in C++

Tags: c++

### EDIT

I found the `memcpy` definition has told us about its undefined behavior when `target` and `src` has overlap:

`The memcpy() function copies n bytes from memory area src to memory area dst.  If dst and src overlap, behavior is undefined.Applications in which dst and src might overlap should use memmove(3) instead.`

### Original Question

I have a simple program that looks like this:

```
static void RotateLeft(bool *In, int len, int loop) {
    for(int i = 0;i< 28;i++) {
        LOGI("%d -> %d", i, In[i]);
    }
    bool Tmp[256] = {0};
    memcpy(Tmp, In, loop);
    memcpy(In, In + loop, len - loop);

    LOGI("len = %d, loop = %d", len, loop);  // <--- always 28 and 1

    for(int i = 0;i< 28;i++) {
        LOGI("%d -> %d", i, In[i]);  <----- broken
    }

    memcpy(In + len - loop, Tmp, loop);
}


RotateLeft(`bool array`, 28, 1)
```

It is weird that this program doesn't work right on the `arm64-v8a` platform (but works well on other platforms):

The input array is something like this:

```
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 ...
```

The rotated array should be:

```
0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0...
```

But it actually outputs:

```
0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 ...
```

### UPDATE

Here's how this program allocate array:

```
bool K[64], *KL=&K[0], *KR=&K[28];

// do something fill `K`

RotateLeft(KR, 28, 1);
```

Comment: Why not use [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)?

Comment: This is an existing project, I want to understand what is going on here, and why its broken.

Comment: Is "bool array" a string? Or is there another array?

Comment: What you posted is incomplete, but in your second `memcpy` call source and destination potentially overlap which triggers undefined behavior, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy.

Comment: @MrROY *I have a simple program that looks like this:* -- Not so simple, if it were, there would be no issues.  Plus `static_assert(sizeof(bool) == 1, "This won't work")` -- Try that anywhere in one of your functions and see if that code even compiles on the platform that it isn't working for.  The algorithm functions such as `std::rotate` stops these corner cases and wrong assumptions from becoming an issue.

Comment: *Rotate a bool array in C++* -- Using `std::rotate` -- `static void RotateLeft(bool *In, int len, int loop) { std::rotate(In, In + loop, In + len); }`

Comment: Thanks guys, `std::rotate` works perfect, but I still don't understand why `memcpy` fails, I printed sizeof(bool), both platforms are `1`.

Comment: @MrROY -- If the source and destination overlap, then `memcpy` has undefined behavior.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes they have some overlap, but the destination is expected to be overridden and it works on 32-bit platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying assumption for this code is that `sizeof(bool)` is 1.  Unfortunately, this is not guaranteed by the C++ standard as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4897859/3723423). So your code is completely compiler dependent.

Therefore use `std::copy()` whenever you can instead of [`memcpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy).  Or use [`std::rotate()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) as suggested by [NathanOlivier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4342498/nathanoliver) in the comments.

*By the way, it's unrelated, but you'd better make sure that `loop>=0 && loop<256 && len>=loop` if you want to avoid undefined behavior.*

Comment: Thanks, `std::rotate` works perfect, but I still don't understand why `memcpy` fails, I printed sizeof(bool), both platforms are `1`.

Comment: Can you show the values of len and loop that you are using, as well as the size of the array, and how you've allocated this array ?

Comment: thanks for your help, I've updated these information. This is a pretty old program, I was just wondering the reason it fails.

Comment: Don't be fooled by the "this is an old program" stuff.  There are plenty of old programs with existing bugs which are either discovered by new, eagle-eyed C++ programmers, or during a port of the program to another platform / compiler and then things fall apart.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to port this one to Android, though `std:rotate` saved my life, I still can't understand that. Maybe its time to get over it...

Comment: Ok, you start at KR, so you're working with K[28]..K[55].  As you don't show the full 28 bytes at that location, I can only guess, that the last digit that is memcopied appears twice because your LOGI display function is before the final memcpy that 't will write the char at the right place.  Eg, if you have 0 0 1 and copy to the left the first len-1 bytes, you'll get 0 1 1 (the last 1 is still the original 1). Only after the final memcpy (there's no logging afterwards), will you get 0 1 0 as expected.