# Different outputs of sizeof operator in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, sizeof

Different outputs of `sizeof()` operator in C and C++.

**In C:**

```
int main() 
{
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(1 == 1));
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
4
```

**In C++:**

```
int main() 
{
    std::cout << sizeof(1 == 1) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
1
```

Questions:

- Why are the outputs different?
- Is `sizeof` independent of the OS or compiler?
- Is it dependent on language?

Comment: `sizeof(bool)` and `sizeof(wchar_t)` are implementation-defined

Comment: Why is this question downvoted?

Comment: `sizeof('a')` differs too.

Comment: @lilezek I did not downvote, but probably because the question is indeed not particularly useful. After all, C and C++ are different languages, they have subtle and not so subtle differences since the dawn of C++. Expecting arbitrary code to behave the same just shows neglect of that simple fact.

Comment: @rsp it even more funny. If you take the same family of C compilers for different targets you will get the different results. For example `avr gcc` sizeof(1==0) will 2 and `ARM gcc` 4 :). Those deliberations are completely useless

Comment: @lilezek mmm..probably lack of research? [google result](https://www.google.com/search?q=result+of+comparison+operator+in+c+vs+c%2B%2B&oq=result+of+comparison+operator+in+c+vs+c%2B%2B&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1540.7416.0.7627.12.12.0.0.0.0.169.1172.6j5.11.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.9.888...33i22i29i30k1.Z3ZQp0h6H4o)
 and the [secnd hit](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/results-of-comparison-operations-in-c-and-c/)??

Comment: "Is sizeof not depend on the OS" --> No - for example an OS need not even exist.  "... or Compiler?" --> Yes. It is a complier choice.  The selection is primarily based on the processor.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. It makes no sense to say "is this language dependent". Every feature of a language depends on that language.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this has been asked many times before.

Comment: "Why are the outputs different?" - because C and C++ are different languages, with different semantics.  Most importantly, C is *not a subset* of C++ - there are legal C programs that are *not* legal C++ programs, and the behavior of programs that are legal in both languages are not guaranteed to be the same in both languages.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) draft ([c11](/questions/tagged/c11)):

**6.5.9 Equality operators**

> The `==` (equal to) and `!=` (not equal to) operators are analogous to the relational operators except for their lower precedence. Each of the operators yields `1` if the specified relation is true and `0` if it is false. **The result has type** `int`.

Therefore, the `sizeof(1 == 1)` will return equal value to `sizeof(int)` which is *implementation defined* and in your case it is `4`.

---

According to [N4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) draft ([c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14)):

**5.10 Equality operators**

> The `==` (equal to) and the `!=` (not equal to) operators group left-to-right. The operands shall have arithmetic, enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type, or type `std::nullptr_t`. The operators `==` and `!=` both yield `true` or `false`, i.e., **a result of type** `bool`.

Therefore, the `sizeof(1 == 1)` will return equal value to `sizeof(bool)` which is *implementation defined* and in your case it is `1`.

Comment: Both `sizeof( int )` and `sizeof( bool )` are *implementation defined*.  They aren't fixed at `4` and `1`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438794/is-the-size-of-c-int-2-bytes-or-4-bytes and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897844/is-sizeofbool-defined

Comment: @AndrewHenle, thanks for your comment but I didn't mention that they have fixed value. Anyway I edited my answer to be more cleaner, emphasizing the fact that the results of `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(bool)` are implementation defined.

Answer (score 15):

In `C` result of `==` and `!=` operators is `int`

According to [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) draft - **6.5.9 Equality operators**

`4` means `sizeof(int)`, but it depends on architecture.

---

In `C++` result of `==` and `!=` operators is `bool`

According to [N4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) draft - **5.10 Equality operators**

`1` means `sizeof(bool)` the size cannot be smaller than one byte. But it would be legal to be larger than one byte.

Comment: C has a built-in type `_Bool`, but it is a late add-on and not used everywhere that it could (should?) be.

Comment: You say C doesn't have a built-in Boolean type, but it does.  You should reword your answer.

Comment: "not used everywhere" --> All C99, C11 compliant compilers have `_Bool`.

Comment: @chux I'm reading 'not used everywhere' as 'not fully integrated into the language'. The result of `1==1` is `int` in C whereas a more comprehensive integration of `_Bool` would presumably revise that. Though it's difficult see any measurable benefit.

Comment: @Persixty An interesting idea, yet a revision to `1==1` to something that is not `int` would break much code base.  Such is the effect of adding improvements vs. legacy choices that carry momentum - for good or ill.

Comment: @chux I'm not advocating. But given "integer promotions" I can only think things like the original question and `_Generic` would differ. My problem is except for intellectual purity I don't see what it would add.

Answer (score 7):

Because the type of the result in C is `int` (and 4 bytes is a typical size) and in C++ it's `bool` (and 1 is the typical size for that).

These values are implementation dependent.

Here's a C11 program that demonstrates that using `_Generic` (typical output `int 4`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void what_int(){
    printf("int %lu",sizeof(int));
}

void what_other(){
    printf("other ?");
}

#define what(x) _Generic((x), \
    int : what_int(),\
    default: what_other()\
)

int main(void) {

    what(1==1);

    return 0;
}
```

Here's a C++ program that demonstrates that using template specializaton (typical output `bool 1`):

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void what(T x){
   std::cout<<"other "<<sizeof(T);
}

template<>
void what(bool x){
   std::cout<<"bool "<<sizeof(bool);
}


int main(){
    what(1==1);
    return 0;
}
```

I can't readily think of any code that is both C and C++ that would have a different outcome. Please accept that as a challenge.