# MPI_BYTE error in allreduce on cluster

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, cluster-computing

MPI_BYTE runs perfect on one cluster but throws an error on the other one.
Is there any reason for this, as sizeof(bool)=1 BYTE and I like 1 BYTE to be reduced.
here is the code

```
int main( int argcs, char *pArgs[] )
{

 MPI_Init( &argcs, &pArgs );

   int my_rank, comsize;

    MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank );

    MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comsize );

    bool sb=false;

    if(my_rank==comsize-1)
    {
      sb=true;
    }

    bool rb=true;

    MPI_Request request0;

    double t1;

    t1 = MPI_Wtime();

MPI_Iallreduce( &sb, &rb, sizeof(bool), MPI_BYTE, MPI_MAX, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request0 );

    MPI_Wait( &request0, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE );

    double   t2 = MPI_Wtime(); 

     MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: Please post the error message and more information about the systems where it works / fails...

Comment: Is one cluster little endian and the other big endian ?

Answer (score 2):

I do not think the standard allows you to use `MPI_BYTE` with a `C` `bool`.

FWIW, in `Fortran` you can use `MPI_LOGICAL`.

Your statement `sizeof(bool) == 1` is indeed incorrect, please refer to [Is sizeof(bool) defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897844/is-sizeofbool-defined) for the details.

From my point of view, your program is incorrect and has hence an undefined behavior.

I am afraid you have to manually convert `bool` to `byte` in `C`, and then you can use `MPI_BYTE`.