# Difference in output for sizeof operator for boolean values in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, size, sizeof

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%d",sizeof(true));
    printf("%d",sizeof(false));
}
```

The output of the above code in C++ is 11 and in C is 44. Why is there a difference in the output?

Comment: `sizeof` yields a `size_t`, no? Therefore the `%d` is UB. (Kinda irrelevant to your question, but it's good to know :)...)

Comment: In C `true` and `false` are macros for `1` and `0` so they are integer literals, therefore your program returning the `sizeof(int)`. In C++ the size of bool is implementation defined not necessary 1.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. C++ hasn't been a superset of C for many, many years.

Answer (score 2):

In C, `true` and `false` are macros defined in `<stdbool.h>` that expand to the integer constants 1 and 0, which have type `int`, per C 2018 7.18 3. The size of `int` is implementation-defined, and 4 is a common size.

In C++, `true` and `false` are literals with `bool` type, per C++ 2017 draft n4659 5.13.6 1. The size of the `bool` type is implementation-defined, per C++ 8.3.3 1, so you may get 1 for it, which is common in C++ implementations.

(Use `%zu` to print sizes obtained with `sizeof`, not `%d`.)

Comment: @Brian I assume that someone thinks that this is a question that have been asked several times, and that you should mark it as a dup instead of answering it. Not me who dv:d though.

Answer (score 1):

`true` and `false` have different meanings in C vs C++.

In `C`, my copy of `stdbool.h` defines `true` and `false` as follows:

```
#define true         1
#define false        0
```

That is, they are both macros for the literals `1` and `0`, respectively. In C, numeric literals default to the type `int`, which on most systems is `4` bytes. Hence, we have `sizeof(true) == sizeof(false) == sizeof(int)`, which on your system is `4`.

In contrast, C++ includes a distinctive boolean type. [While not required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897844/is-sizeofbool-defined-in-the-c-language-standard) by the standard, most implementations provide `bool`s that occupy only one byte. This is the case on your system, hence `sizeof(bool) == 1`.

Comment: Detail: In C, 0 & 1 are _constants_.  `"1"` is an example of a _literal_, a _string literal_.

Answer (score 1):

While the C standard does not require the cpp part of the header still if you look at widely used compilers like GCC implementation of the stdbool.h (Clang's one similar) file you see

```
#ifndef _STDBOOL_H
#define _STDBOOL_H

#ifndef __cplusplus

#define bool        _Bool
#define true        1
#define false        0

#else /* __cplusplus */

/* Supporting <stdbool.h> in C++ is a GCC extension.  */
#define _Bool        bool
#define bool        bool
#define false        false
#define true        true

#endif /* __cplusplus */

/* Signal that all the definitions are present.  */
#define __bool_true_false_are_defined        1

#endif        /* stdbool.h */
```

In C case `true` and `false` are essentially integer literals so you will get the `sizeof(int)`. But in C++ case virtually nothing happen with this header so you will get the `sizeof(bool)` which is usually 1, but it is implementation defined actually.

If you would do this in C++ then you would get similar result like in C.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

#define true 1
#define false 0

int main()
{
    printf("%zu",sizeof(true));
    printf("%zu",sizeof(false));
}
```

Comment: That is a `<stdbool.h>` file, not the `<stdbool.h>` file. It shows what one implementation does, not what the standards require. Questions like this should be answered primarily by reference to what the standards say.