# Why is my solution(Square Dance - google jam problem) giving "wrong answer"?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I made few archive problems from Google Jam 2020 competition.
First I made 5 problems from qualfication round and it all works OK. Only last problem my algorithm is too slow so I don't get max points.
But OK. I go to Round 1A and there are 3 problems. Problem 3 is called "Square Dance".
It's description can be found here:
https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/000000000019fd74/00000000002b1355

I made a program. My program pass sample case as success.
I also tested my program to few other situations and it works OK.
But when I upload my solution I got "Wrong Answer" in google test case set.

For example. This situations works perfect for my solution:

1
5 5
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 2 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1

It gives answer 66 because there will be 3 rounds:

1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 2 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
26

1 1 1 1 1
1 1 0 1 1
1 0 2 0 1
1 1 0 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
22

1 1 0 1 1
1 1 0 1 1
0 0 2 0 0
1 1 0 1 1
1 1 0 1 1
18

So everything works OK.

But why it fails on google test.

Is there somethink that I don't understand?
Or some bug in code? But it works OK for many tested cases that I test...

My source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int sizeX;
int sizeY;
int** map;
bool** eliminateTable;


bool calculateWhoToEliminate()
{
    for (int y = 0; y < sizeY; ++y)
    {
        memset(eliminateTable[y], 0, sizeX);
    }

    bool toEliminate = false;

    for (int y = 0; y < sizeY; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeX; ++x)
        {
            if (map[y][x] == 0)
                continue;

            int skillOfNeightbours = 0;
            int neightboursCount = 0;

            //w lewo
            int px = x - 1;
            while (px >= 0)
            {
                if (map[y][px] != 0)
                {
                    skillOfNeightbours += map[y][px];
                    neightboursCount++;
                    break;
                }
                px--;
            }

            //w prawo
            px = x + 1;
            while (px < sizeX)
            {
                if (map[y][px] != 0)
                {
                    skillOfNeightbours += map[y][px];
                    neightboursCount++;
                    break;
                }
                px++;
            }

            //w gore
            int py = y - 1;
            while (py >= 0)
            {
                if (map[py][x] != 0)
                {
                    skillOfNeightbours += map[py][x];
                    neightboursCount++;
                    break;
                }
                py--;
            }

            //w dol
            py = y + 1;
            while (py < sizeY)
            {
                if (map[py][x] != 0)
                {
                    skillOfNeightbours += map[py][x];
                    neightboursCount++;
                    break;
                }
                py++;
            }

            if (map[y][x] * neightboursCount < skillOfNeightbours)
            {
                eliminateTable[y][x] = true;
                toEliminate = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return toEliminate;
}

void eliminate()
{
    for (int y = 0; y < sizeY; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeX; ++x)
        {
            if (eliminateTable[y][x])
            {
                map[y][x] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

int countScore()
{
    int score = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < sizeY; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeX; ++x)
        {
            score += map[y][x];
        }
    }
    return score;
}

int solve()
{
    int score = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        score += countScore();
        if (calculateWhoToEliminate())
        {
            eliminate();
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }       
    }
    return score;
}

int main()
{
    int testCasesCount;
    cin >> testCasesCount;
    for (int test = 1; test <= testCasesCount; ++test)
    {
        cin >> sizeX;
        cin >> sizeY;
        map = new int*[sizeY];
        eliminateTable = new bool*[sizeY];
        for (int y = 0; y < sizeY; ++y)
        {
            map[y] = new int[sizeX];
            eliminateTable[y] = new bool[sizeX];

            for (int x = 0; x < sizeX; ++x)
            {
                cin >> map[y][x];
            }
        }

        int r = solve();

        cout << "Case #" << test << ": " << r << endl;

        for (int y = 0; y < sizeY; ++y)
        {
            delete map[y];
            delete eliminateTable[y];
        }
        delete map;
        delete eliminateTable;
    }

    //system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should add a language tag to your question. :)

Comment: Sorry. I am new here. I fixed it.

Comment: `bool **`, `int **map` -- You're including `<vector>`, so why are you not using it here?  There is no need for two-star pointers.

Comment: "description can be found here:" - *No*! Stackoverflow questions should be self contained. Everything relevant should be *in* the question, *not* behind external links that rot over time.

Comment: `memset(eliminateTable[y], 0, sizeX);` -- This is not correct.  This should be `memset(eliminateTable[y], 0, sizeX * sizeof(bool));`.  If you had used `std::fill_n` then the syntax would work, i.e. `std::fill_n(eliminateTable[y], sizeX, 0);`.  You were partially filling in the `bool` array with 0 values, thus maybe this was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Whether this fixes the problem or not, this definitely is a bug:

`memset(eliminateTable[y], 0, sizeX);`

This should be:

`memset(eliminateTable[y], 0, sizeX * sizeof(bool));`

The `memset` function third argument is the number of bytes, not the number of items.

Possibly that `memset` call you were doing was only partially filling the `bool` array with 0, thus you were not getting the correct results due to utilizing uninitialized portions of the `bool` array.

Comment: No. sizeof(bool) is 1.

Comment: [Please read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897844/is-sizeofbool-defined-in-the-c-language-standard).  Do not assume what it is -- actually write the correct code.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I found the solution.

1. score has to be long long
2. not:
       cin >> sizeX;
       cin >> sizeY;
   but:
       cin >> sizeY;
       cin >> sizeX;

because first is rows, then columns.